# How to use background service to show custom dialog for incoming VOIP call in case of app is not in use

Tags: android

I am developing and VOIP based android app. In case the app is offline i.e user is not currently using and if a incoming call arrives I need to show a dialog similar to whatsapp calling even when my app screen is locked.

Below is the method which senses incoming call

```
public void onIncomingCall(CallClient callClient, Call incomingCall) {
            call = incomingCall;
            Window oWindow = getActivity().getWindow();

            oWindow.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON
                    + WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
                    + WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

            dialogincoming = new Dialog(getActivity());
            dialogincoming.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            dialogincoming.setCancelable(false);
            dialogincoming.setContentView(R.layout.incomingcall);
            imgreceive=(ImageView) dialogincoming.findViewById(R.id.accept);
            imgdecline=(ImageView) dialogincoming.findViewById(R.id.reject);
            imgreceive.startAnimation(animation1);
            imgdecline.startAnimation(animation1);

            dialogincoming.show();
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.ring);
            mp.start();

            imgreceive.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
             mp.stop();
             dialogincoming.dismiss();
            call.answer();



    }
});
```

Comment: where did you put this method ? for example, when the app is killed, so you'll get push notification ? or you using socket ?

Comment: The issue is solved by using GCM listener long back just missed to update

Comment: Okay, Would be nice if you share your solution to help to community. I'll vote for you :-).